# Prevent injection of html tags in SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have created a web site with asp.net 3.5 and SQL Server 2005 on the back end

We have created admin site for updating data in the database by using secure user account.
I working for live for some time.

After some times we found that some specific `html` tags are getting inserted into string fields of the database.

It seems some kind of attack

Can any one suggest me how to prevent from that attack.

Comment: When and how you insert values to database??

Comment: We are using direct sql queries for inserting values in the database.

Answer (score 3):

What you have is probably a SQL injection attack that is being used to deploy a cross site scripting attack.  However this may possibly not be coming from the asp.net application itself.  By default ASP.NET web applications will turn on request validation which blocks posts that may *look* to be a cross site scripting attack (they will get a "dangerous request 500 error when posting HTML").  If you have turned that off then you're probably exposing yourself.

You should use an ORM like LINQ to Entities or at least be using parametrized queries for any SQL queries you are executing, this will go a long way in protecting you from SQL Injection attacks.  You still have the issue however of cross site scripting.  Take a look at the Microsoft **[AntiXSS library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814.aspx)** to ensure that you are protected.

The other problem you will have is with people internally or through another application that may be inserting into your database (if you're using it as a common database).  For that the best you can do is to put a check constraint that fails when you match HTML on a regular expression.  Check out **[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)** article on details.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a Cross-Site scripting attack.

You can set the "validateRequest" to "true" at the application level(in config), or set it at the page level in page directive.

Please read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx)

Comment: The problem with this is that an exception is thrown by ASP.net when any tags are used. This isn't the best way to handle invalid input in my opinion

Answer (score -1):

You should *always* encode any input from the user to prevent cross site scripting and SQL injection attacks.Server.HtmlDecode and Server.HtmlEncode were there precisely for this reason.

On top of that, if you want to prevent Html tags altogether, scrub the input of the unwanted tags using a Regular Expression.

Comment: Data should be encoded/escaped *at* the appropriate usage site - not arbitrarily "before insert".

Comment: Not sure exactly why you're stating that? I didn't say the stage was here or there, I just said that data should always be encoded. What you've said effectively means nothing